# Problema con raphael js

Tags: javascript

Tengo un inconveniente al adjuntar `raphael.js.min` automáticamente me bloquea el resto de funcionalidades que realizan otros `scripts` como por ejemplo la paginación de mi tabla. He probado cambiándolo de posición pero sigue el inconveniente. Quisiera saber si existe alguna otra alternativa que haga lo mismo que `Raphaël` pero sin dañar el resto de `scripts`.

Lo que hace `Raphaël` es poner los rectangulos azules que se ven a continuación cada vez que se de clic en cualquiera de ellos debe salir un `alert`. 
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código raphael:

```
var rsr = Raphael('map', '2725', '1717'); 

var regions = [];

var plano2 = rsr.rect(474.31512, 27.257416, 15.82637, 73.479187); 
plano2.attr({id: 'plano2', x: '398.31512', y: '23.257416', fill: '#5555ff', 'stroke-width': '0', 'stroke-opacity': '1'}).data('id', 'plano2'); 
regions.push(plano2);

var plano3 = rsr.rect(110.20976, 136.39427, 11.869713, 58.218128); 
plano3.attr({id: 'plano3', x: '90.20976', y: '136.39427', fill: '#2a2aff', 'stroke-width': '0', 'stroke-opacity': '1'}).data('id', 'plano3'); 
regions.push(plano3);

var plano1 = rsr.rect(22.591152, 25.006752, 133.39301, 19.217632); 
plano1.attr({id: 'plano1', x: '5.591152', y: '23.006752', fill: '#2a2aff', 'stroke-width': '0', 'stroke-opacity': '1'}).data('id', 'plano1');
regions.push(plano1);


for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {

    // Change Yorkshire's fill colour to gold
    if (regions[i].data('id') == 'heaven-on-earth') {
        regions[i].node.setAttribute('fill', 'gold');
    }

    // Showing off
    regions[i].mouseover(function (e) {
        this.node.style.opacity = 0.7;
        document.getElementById('region-name').innerHTML = this.data('region');
    });

    regions[i].mouseout(function (e) {
        this.node.style.opacity = 1;
    });

    regions[i].click(function (e) {
        alert("asd");
    });
}
```

Los scripts que uso:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>  
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--Scripts tabla -->
<script src="assets/js/Table/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tablaInfoNeveras').DataTable();
    });
</script>
<script src="amcharts/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="amcharts/serial.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="amcharts/amstock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar algo de código para reproducir tu problema?

Comment: @JavierCárdenas ya lo agregue como edición en mi pregunta. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si solo necesitas situar los rectángulos y detectar cuando haces click en ellos, puedes prescindir de `Raphaël` (este tipo de librerías deberías usarla si vas a crear cosas más complejas). Puedes crear el elemento `SVG` y los rectángulos sólo con `Vanilla JavaScript`. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var cont = document.getElementById("container");
var namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svg = document.createElementNS(namespace, "svg");

addAttributes(svg, {"id": "map", "width": 800, "height": 600});

addRectangle(svg, clickRectangle, {"id": "plano1", "x": 10, "y": 10, "width": 100, "height": 50, "fill": "#2a2aff", "stroke-width": 0, "stroke-opacity": 1});

addRectangle(svg, clickRectangle, {"id": "plano2", "x": 150, "y": 10, "width": 200, "height": 100, "fill": "#2a2aff", "stroke-width": 0, "stroke-opacity": 1});

cont.appendChild(svg);

function addRectangle (svg, click, attrs) {

    var rect = document.createElementNS(namespace, "rect");
    addAttributes(rect, attrs);
    svg.appendChild(rect);
    
    rect.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if (click) { click.call(null, rect.getAttribute("id")); }
    });
  
}

function addAttributes (el, attrs) {
    for (var prop in attrs) {
        el.setAttribute(prop, attrs[prop]);
    }
}

function clickRectangle (id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

```css
#map {
    width: 100%;
}

#map rect:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
    transition: opacity .25s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```